# HTTP Session management in Web application (Ajax/Servlet)

Tags: ajax, session, servlets

Currently I have a webpage, with login credentials, which when provided with the appropriate ones, allows the user to login. Now, after this login (where validation is done via ajax call to a Servlet), the user is redirected to a different page (with different URL). How do I create/manage a session ?

I would require the following functionality :

1. If the user closes the tab/browser window, the user should be made to logout.
2. Further if the user generates no activity for a long period of time (about 15 minutes), user should be logged out automatically.

Note : I don't want to rely on cookies. Is there any other way ?

Also do I need to perform repeated polling to the server ? (So that if the server doesn't get requests after a certain period of time, the session is made to expire...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You really can't do that.
2. See the docs for HttpSession http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet   There are two methods you will want to know about for this:

   `session.getMaxInactiveInterval()`   Returns the maximum time interval, in seconds, that the servlet container will keep this session open between client accesses.

   `setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)` Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session.

And to create a session, of course, is as simple as a call to `session.setAttribute("somename", variable)` followed immediately by `setMaxInactiveInterval` if you don't like the default session length.

Comment: Your last method call doesn't create an HttpSession, it just sets an attribute.

Comment: And the difference between the two, functionally speaking, is what? The session is either created automatically when you hit the page, or when you first do something with the session object, right?